# Inequality with directional derivative and norm of vector

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, hamilton-jacobi-equation

In one of my lectures, we dealt with the Hopf-Lax formula for the solution of the Hamilton-Jacobi equation with a free particle:

$$\partial_t u(t,x) + \frac{1}{2} \lvert \nabla u(x,t) \rvert^2=0 $$

We assume that the initial condition at some $t_0>0$ is globally Lipschitz and take some point $(x,t_0+s)$, $x \in \mathbb{R^d}, s>0$ where the time and space derivatives exists. For this point, we define $ \eta = (x-y)/s$ where $y$ is a minimising point in the Hopf-Lax formula, which means

$$\min_{z \in \mathbb{R^d}} \bigg\{ \frac{|x-z|^2}{2s} + u^0(z) \bigg\}= \frac{|x-y|^2}{2s} + u^0(y)$$

We then show that

$$\partial_{t} u(t,x) + \eta \cdot \nabla u(t,x) - \frac{1}{2}|\eta|^2\geq 0$$

Now the claim is that the LHS is maximised for $\eta = \nabla u(t,x).$ Why? The term $\eta \cdot \nabla u(t,x)$ is maximised for $\eta = \nabla u(t,x)$ due to Cauchy-Schwarz, but why does it hold with this additional negative term $\frac{1}{2}|\eta|^2?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}-a^2/2$ to be maximized, $\mathbf{a}$ must be parallel to $\mathbf{b}$. So we have that $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b} = ab$. Thus we are trying to maximize $a(b-a/2)$ with respect to $a$, which occurs at $a=b$. Since $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are parallel with the same magnitude, they are equal.

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer. What does $ab$ stand for? I am not familiar with the notation. Why should $\mathbb{a}$ and $\mathbb{b}$ be parallel in order to maximise $a \cdot b - \frac{a^2}{2}$?

Comment: @Len Suppose $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ aren't parallel. Consider the vector $\mathbf{a}'$ with the same magnitude as $\mathbf{a}$ (that is, $a^2 = a'^2$) but parallel to $\mathbf{b}$. Then we have $\mathbf{a}'\cdot\mathbf{b} \ge \mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}$. So $\mathbf{a}'\cdot\mathbf{b}-a'^2/2\ge  \mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}-a^2/2$.